# struct nameidata-Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel

I'm working on a Linux kernel module and trying to apply a kprobe on `path_openat` function. After that, I need to work with the `nameidata` structure, which is the first of three parameters of that function.

I've included `namei.h`, but it doesn't recognize the structure and return `invalid use of undefined type struct nameidata`.

Is it inaccessible to programmers? By the way, I have the same problem with `struct open_flags`.

I've tried to manually import the structure with a custom header but it isn't a good solution in particular for portability.

This kprobe is a parth of bigger project: I'm trying to realize a custom reference monitor that check operation like open, unlink, rename etc on file and directory. This is path_openat pre handler:

```
static int openat_pre_handler(struct kretprobe_instance *p, struct pt_regs *the_regs){
    // path openat pre handler

    struct nameidata * nd;
    struct open_flags * op_flags;
    struct inode * inode;
    struct filename * pathname_struct;
    const char *pathname;
    int flags;

    // Check if the module is OFF or REC-OFF, in that case doesn't need to execute the post handler
    if(monitor->state == 0 || monitor->state == 1)
        goto end;


    atomic_inc((atomic_t*)&open_audit_counter);

    // x86-64 syscall calling convention: %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %r10, %r8 and %r9.
   
    /*path_openat(struct nameidata *nd, const struct open_flags *op, unsigned flags)*/

    // nameidata is the first parameter, it contains the inode and filename.
    nd = (struct nameidata *) the_regs->di; 
    inode = nd->inode;
    pathname_struct = nd->name;
    pathname = pathname_struct->name;

    // open_flag is the second parameter
    op_flags = (struct open_flags *) the_regs->si; 
    flags = op_flags->open_flag;
    
    // Check if the file is opened WRITE-ONLY or READ-WRITE
    if (flags & O_WRONLY || flags & O_RDWR){
        
        // Check if file is protected
        if (inode_in_protected_paths(inode->i_ino)){
            // ADD WRITE-REPORT ON LOG FILE
            printk("%s: Access on %s blocked correctly \n", MODNAME,pathname);
            //print_flag(flags);
            //The kretprobe post handler should be executed: the access must be blocked
            return 0;
        }

    } 

end: 
    // Doesn't execute the post handler, the access is legit
    return 1;
}
```

I may have included more than necessary:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>    
#include <linux/spinlock.h>  
#include <linux/file.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/path.h> 
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/fdtable.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <linux/dcache.h>
```

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Now there is the example.

Comment: Resolved: nameidata is directly defined within namei.c. It seems that the developers have designed it to be used exclusively within that file and not to be accessed externally